# I cannot run android emulator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio-2019

Device error: emulator: Android emulator version 28.0.25.0 (build_id 5395263) (CL:77b96786ddf712e1477c6e05cddb09526043faef)
emulator: Found AVD name 'my_device_1'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator: argv[0]: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\default\x86_64\

emulator: Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\default\x86_64\kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator: Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\default\x86_64\

emulator: emuDirName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.

I have no idea how to run this, this is my first dabbling with android at all.

Does anyone know how to proceed successfully past this? Thank you

Comment: You need to determine the reason qemu isn't installed

Comment: You have not provided us enough information to determine the reason QEMU isn't installed.

Comment: Have you installed [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/download/#windows)?  If you have not installed it, then you need to install it try running the emulator again, once you have attempted that your question should be updated with any relevant information.

Comment: Rahmound, I have now installed QEMU as you suggested. It is strange though. The error message states "cant find emulator executable" at path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"  However, I can copy this right out of the message and navigate to that path and I do in fact see this executable exists in the directory from the error message. I am using Visual Studio 2019, if that makes a difference.

Comment: ramhound, sorry misspelled you name earlier